# Error: No such partition. Grub rescue>

Tags: dual-boot

After installing Ubuntu 11.10, alongside windows 7, when PC restart automatically first time, I got this message, just below the table, PCI Device Listing,

```
Error: No such partition
Grub Rescue>
```

Now PC is not booting at all, even if I restart it.

Comment: Please see the answer of this similar question [no such partition grub rescue error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145930/error-no-such-partition-grub-rescue)

Answer (score 0):

Well... since that PC is now un-usable for a while:

Using another PC, download "[Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/boot-repair-disk.iso/download)." Burn the ISO image to a CD and boot from it. It should work. (It did for me.)