# error: no such partition. grub rescue>

Tags: grub2, partitioning, filesystem, grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue)

please help me. I don't know how it has happened. I was recovering some data with Photorec (not sure if it's important) and at night I woke up, it was still running. I was sleepy and I turned off my notebook, not closing anything, I  think recovering was not finished yet. Now, when I turn on NoteBook it is like error...I've tried everything I found on the Internet, but nothing worked. Here is what it does and what I've tried:

```
error: no such partition
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5)
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos5)/
error: unknown filesystem.
```

So there are only two and both are unknown filesystems. I'm sorry, I really don't understand those things. Please, please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: this works 100%-do it straightaway...i've done it couple of times-http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.in/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html

Comment: but..I need Ubuntu live CD for this..:/

Comment: yes...you need it any ways...even if you want to use grub rescue the application,you have to do it through a live cd...this mostly happens because of an un-updated (after changes) grub.conf file...

Comment: oh..so how can I get that cd? or usb?

Comment: from the internet(you'll obviously have to use another pc/laptop)...you may download it from here-http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop...OR for torrent links from here-http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads...After downloading the iso image,make a bootable CD/USB using Unetbootin...boot it and follow those instructions

Comment: Thank youu :) one more detail..Does it matter what USB I'll use? ..I've never used Unetbootin before. so I downloaded it and what to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your main issue seems to be on how you create a Live-CD. I suggest you take a look at [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/q/30048/10698) it's a guide on how you create a Live-cd with USB (Unetbootin).

Comment: Thanks, I think I can make it :) ..and my flash will be usable then?

Comment: @Sus just reboot with your usb after you've done the install and **boot from it** (differs from model to model, like press F2 or so), and your computer should boot from the Usb.