# grub is not detecting my partition

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, xubuntu, grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tried to boot Ubuntu, but the GRUB rescue shows up instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-shows-up-instead)

I have following partition in my HDD

/sda1 ntfs 14gb

/sda2 ntfs 14gb boot(windows7 installed here)

/sda3 extended

 /sda5 ntfs 100gb

 /sda6 ext4 5gb root

 /sda7 ext4 2gb swap

 /sda8 ext4 13gb home

after installing ubuntu 10.4.x it is showing only 

**no such parttion

grub rescue>**

 what to do?

Comment: Try the answers from this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145930/error-no-such-partition-grub-rescue)